# AWS CloudWatch Log Metric Filter with JSON key has character space

Tags: amazon-cloudwatchlogs, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

When creating an AWS CloudWatch Log Metric Filter, how would you match terms in JSON Log Events where the key has a character space in the name?

For example, let's assume there's a log line with JSON element like the following...

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerLogStart","Spark Version":"2.4.0-SNAPSHOT"}
```

How would you reference the "Spark Version"? `$."Spark Version"`, `$.Spark Version`, `$.Spark\ Version`, and `$.[Spark Version]` don't work.

I couldn't find the answer in the [AWS Filter and Pattern Syntax documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the time of writing, this is not possible. AWS will probably fix that at some point, but for now the only workaround would be to use the non-JSON syntax and search for the exact string. The following filter:

```
"\"Spark Version\":\"2.4.0-SNAPSHOT\""
```

will match:

```
{"Event":"SparkListenerLogStart","Spark Version":"2.4.0-SNAPSHOT"}
```